# "I would, too" - meaning?

Tags: meaning-in-context

[SCIENCE MAGAZINE](http://www.sciencemag.org/news/2016/01/astronomers-say-neptune-sized-planet-lurks-beyond-pluto)

> - “If you say, ‘We have evidence for Planet X,’ almost any astronomer will say, ‘This again? These guys are clearly crazy.’ **I would, too**,” Brown says.

Does it, “I would, too, mean that I “would also you are crazy”?

Comment: `if you` ... `these guys` the two parts seem disconnected

Comment: Brown's reply doesn't reflect immediately-preceding *These guys are clearly crazy.* He's simply saying that he too would say "This again?" ***just the same as almost any astronomer.***

Comment: @Jasen Well, I'd interpret "these guys" to mean "you" and other people who also say they have such evidence. I suppose it's inconsistent in a strict grammatical sense -- arguably he should have said "This guy is clearly crazy" -- but the meaning in context is pretty clear. And I think the point is to say that many people have made this claim, so he wants to turn it plural somewhere along the line.

Comment: it's not said properly.It means: [if **you say x, any astronomer will say y***.  I would [say they are crazy,] too.

Comment: *You:* the astronomers addressed, and as referred to, by Brown. *These guys:* the same astronomers, but referred to by orthodox astronomers other than Brown, who are not addressing them.

Answer (score 1):

The following would be the expanded version of what Brown would say:

> I too, just like any astronomer you ask, would say that people who are claiming that they have evidence for Planet X are crazy.

The pronoun *we* in this passage refers to people or any person in general and not to the two people, one of whom is Brown, discussing this. This is just one of the many uses that the pronoun *we* can have in English. For more details, see [**definition 1.2**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/we) in Oxford Dictionaries.

A couple of examples:

> **We** should eat as varied and well-balanced a diet as possible.
>
> One day, **we** will all die.

Comment: *We* is not “any person in general”, it's the hypothetical astronomers quoted as claiming evidence for Planet X.